# Defining an ellipse around data points

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, scatter

I have a question/idea that I am not sure how to do.

I have a scatter plot of X vs. Y

[image: scatter plot example]

I can draw a rectangle and then pick all the points within in.

Ideally I want to define a ellipse as it better captures the shape and exclude all the points that are outside it.

How does one do this? is it even possible? I drew the plot using matplotlib.

I used Linear Regression (LR) to fit the points but thats not really what I am looking for. 
I want to define APPROXIMATELY a ellipse to cover as many points as possible within it and then exclude points outside it. How can I define an equation/code to pick the ones inside ?

Comment: What is your point? I don't see how you are using a linear regression to draw the rectangle?

Comment: Can look at the draggable rectangle demo here: http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/users/event_handling.html#draggable-rectangle-exercise

Comment: Well, I don't know how difficult it is to implement, but some `Data Mining` algorithms will cover your needs. Take a look at `k-means` algorithm or `GMM` (Gaussian model).

Comment: Do you have the data, or are you just poking at a chart?  This would be easy with a function and list comprehension.

Comment: I do have a Y=mx+b function and plotted the original using numpy arrays.

Comment: You may find [this SE.Mathematics question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate) helpful. But do you really _need_ an ellipse? Consider using a rotated rectangle - it's easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data structure that is represented in the graph, you can do this with a function and a list comprehension.

If you have the data in a list like this:

```
# Made up data
lst = [
    # First element is X, second is Y.
    (0,0),
    (92,20),
    (10,0),
    (13,40),
    (27,31),
    (.5,.5),
]

def shape_bounds(x):
    """
    Function that returns lower and upper bounds for y based on x

    Using a circle as an example here.
    """
    r = 4
    # A circle is x**2 + y**2 = r**2, r = radius
    if -r <= x <= r:
        y = sqrt(r**2-x**2)
        return -y, y
    else:
        return 1, -1 # Remember, returns lower, upper.  
        # This will fail any lower < x < upper test.        

def in_shape(elt):
    """
    Unpacks a pair and tests if y is inside the shape bounds given by x
    """
    x, y = elt
    lower_bound, upper_bound = shape_bounds(x)
    if lower_bound < y < upper_bound:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Demo walkthrough
for elt in lst:
    x, y = elt
    print x, y
    lower_bound, upper_bound = shape_bounds(x)
    if lower_bound < y < upper_bound:
        print "X: {0}, Y: {1} is in the circle".format(x, y)

# New list of only points inside the shape
new_lst = [x for x in lst if in_shape(x)]
```

As for an ellipse, try changing the shape equation based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate)